# Convergence of the taylor series of $\ln(1+x)$?

Tags: taylor-expansion

> Show that $\lim\limits_{x\to N} R_N(x)$ does not exist for $1 \le x \le \infty$, given that $\lim\limits_{x\to N}$$R_N(x) = \lim\limits_{x\to N} \int_0^x \frac{(t-x)^N}{(1+t)^{(N+1)}} \,\mathrm{d}t$

Current Attempt:

- Split function into $\int_0^1 R_N(x) \,\mathrm{d}x + \int_1^\infty R_N(x) \,\mathrm{d}x$
- Focus on second half

From here I have an integral, but have no clue what to do with it to prove its convergence. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange! Your question doesn't quite make sense to me. You express a limit of $R_N(x)$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$. Shouldn't you be trying to compute $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^x \frac{(t-x)^N}{(1+t)^{N+1}} \ dt$?

Comment: Sorry! It should be as N approaches 0!

Comment: No worries, definitely double check the question and make sure there are no other typos :).

Comment: There we go, I added in a few other details useful for the workings of this question (just the limits, since that is how we calculate remainder)!